# Open MTP in Explorer instead of WIA - powershell

Tags: powershell, mtp

I have this script to open and browse MTP device

```
$WIAdialog = New-Object -ComObject “WIA.CommonDialog”
$Device = $WIAdialog.ShowSelectDevice()
$Device = $WIAdialog.ShowAcquireImage()
$Device = $WIAdialog.ShowAcquisitionWizard()
$Device = $WIAdialog.ShowDeviceProperties()
$Device = $WIAdialog.ShowItemProperties()
$Device = $WIAdialog.ShowPhotoPrintingWizard()
$Device = $WIAdialog.ShowSelectItems()
$Device = $WIAdialog.ShowTransfer()
```

But this script is loading information about stored pictures which is too slow even at local computer. Is it possible to avoid loading info of pictures to speed up opening and accessing remotely connected devices and/**or to open MTP device in Windows File Explorer instead of some WIA dialog?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access MTP storage with System.IO from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44094188/access-mtp-storage-with-system-io-from-powershell)